# Efficient duplicates search algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I need a script to search efficiently all the duplicates in a one-dimensional array. 
I tried a naive method :

```
for(var i=0, ii<arr.length-1; i<ii; i++)
    for(var j=i+1, jj<arr.length; j<jj; j++)
        if(arr[i] == arr[j])
            // remove the duplicate
```

Very simple but it takes a too long time if the array contains a large set of values. The tables that I use often contain hundreds of thousands of values, so that the number of iterations required for this operation is HUGE !

If someone has an idea !?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array

Comment: unless you have some restrictions on the values I would vote for the dup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a LinkedHashSet or OrderedHashSet implementation, it does not allow duplicates and provides expected O(1) on insertion, lookup, and deletion. Since your OP says you want to remove the duplicates, there is no faster way to do this than O(n). In an array of 1,000,000 items max time was 16ms

- Create a LinkedHashSet hs
- foreach object obj in arr
  -- hs.add(obj);

Complexity is expected O(n) with a good hash function.

Comment: Strictly speaking, hash set does not guarantee `O(n)` complexity.

Comment: I never said that it does, I said that removing duplicates from the dataset is worst case O(n). HashSet guarantees O(1) for operations

Comment: I meant that using of hash set does not guarantee overall `O(n)` complexity. No, hash set does not _guarantee_ O(1) due to possible hash collisions.

Comment: Ok, i try up this solution. A verification before add a value into array seems a good solution for me !

Comment: My mistake, LinkedHashSet or OrderHashSet implementation avoids collisions. Could you explain why it does not guarantee O(n)? If the number of objects in the array are known, capacity can be set.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table (the summary table in the top right corner: `O(1)` average, `O(n)` worst).

Comment: @AlexD a good implementation can achieve O (1) with high probability, which is very very good. Every decent implementation guarantees at least O (1) expected runtime. So the answer here can be implemented in O (n) w.h.p and in practice it will run very fast. No point arguing about that, just edit in the word "expected" and be done with it

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://dreaminginjavascript.wordpress.com/2008/08/22/eliminating-duplicates/) code could be the most efficient way you can do it ..!! Which is nothing but the direct implementation of set .

```
function eliminateDuplicates(arr) {
  var i,
      len=arr.length,
      out=[],
      obj={};

  for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
    obj[arr[i]]=0;
  }
  for (i in obj) {
    out.push(i);
  }
  return out;
}
```